# svn import is giving error

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

i am working on svn project and i am totally newbie.i am learning SVN from tutorialspoint. i have create repository successfully. and created directories for trunk, branches and tags using following commands

```
mkdir /tmp/svn-template
mkdir /tmp/svn-template/trunk
mkdir /tmp/svn-template/branches
mkdir /tmp/svn-template/tags
```

now i want to import that dir to my repository using following command

```
svn import -m 'Create trunk, branches, tags directory structure' /tmp/svn-template/
```

but it gives me an error "
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: Invalid URL '/root/tmp/svn-template'
"

please help me guys

Comment: **Invalid URL** — Despite what browsers are making everybody believe, URLs have to start with a protocol prefix (unless they are relative URLs, something not really possible here).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the last argument, your repository URL.

For example:

```
svn import -m 'Create ...' /tmp/svn-template/ http://svn.myserver.com/repo/svn-template/
```

Be aware that your local copy will not be under version control after that. You must make a checkout of a working copy in another directory.

```
cd /somewhere/else
svn checkout http://svn.myserver.com/repo/svn-template/
```

Comment: i think if you do not add last argument then it will take current path.

Comment: The optional argument is the path, not the url. If you do not inform path, it will assume ".". So you could write `svn import -m 'Create ...' http://svn.myserver.com/repo/svn-template/` but not `svn import -m 'Create ...' /tmp/svn-template/`

Comment: ohk thank you for the answer. right now i am creating svn repository project in php. so can you help me in setting environment ?
i have also asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

change the `SVNPath` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`
to `"SVNPath /var/www/svn/your_project_name"`

```
cd /var/www/svn
```

Now import the dir `/tmp/svn-template`

```
svn import /tmp/svn-template/ http://ip-address/svn/ -m "Create trunk,branches and tags directories"
```